# Excel text string order

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bunch of product codes in Excel. This is what they look like.

000-00021-001-nav

Keep on mind they are all different lengths. I want to reformat them to look like this

NAV-000-00021-001

does anyone know how to do this? Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the cell is in A1, you can use the formula `=CONCATENATE(UPPER(RIGHT(A1,3)),"-",LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-4))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a fairly flexible VBA routine.  The following assumes the string consists of dash separated segments, and that you want to reverse the first and last segments, and that everything will be capitalized.

It does allow you to use a different delimiter, but that is an optional argument.

To enter this User Defined Function (UDF), **alt-F11** opens the Visual Basic Editor.
Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
Then, from the top menu, select Insert/Module and
paste the code below into the window that opens.

To use this User Defined Function (UDF), enter a formula like

```
=LastToFirst(A1)
```

in some cell.

```
Option Explicit
Function LastToFirst(S As String, Optional sDelimit As String = "-") As String
    Dim V As Variant
    Dim I As Long
    Dim sTemp As String

V = Split(UCase(S), sDelimit)
    sTemp = V(0)
    V(0) = V(UBound(V))
    V(UBound(V)) = sTemp

LastToFirst = Join(V, sDelimit)

End Function
```

If you want to use a worksheet formula that will reverse the first and last segments, and is **indifferent** to the **length** of the segments or the **number** of segments, you can try this:

```
=UPPER(IFERROR(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",REPT(" ",99)),99))&
MID(A1,FIND("-",A1),LEN(A1)-LEN(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",
REPT(" ",99)),99)))-FIND("-",A1)+1)&LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1),A1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to do this in VBA and not with an Excel expression:

This sounds quite do-able, particularly if VBA has a RIGHT() function (I don't remember whether it does or not).

You'll probably have the least stress if you program it in several statements rather than in one big nested expression.

Exactly how you'd approach it would depend on the characteristics of the string, and what's constant and what isn't.  If the last section of the string is always three characters, for example, you can just determine the length of the string and do some substringing.  If the only thing guaranteed to be constant is the 3 dashes, you'd have to use another function (I forget the name, but one that finds a substring within a string and returns the position) in order to determine where the last dash is located in the string.

I'd approach it something like this (this is pseudocode):

```
' Determine length of string
' Determine starting position of last section
' Extract last section
' Use function - I think it's called UCase() - to convert the extracted last section to uppercase
' Reassemble the string
' Return the string.
```